# How do I validate an email to be compatible with Salesforce's database constraints?

Tags: apex, soql

Suppose I have an email. Suppose I want to insert a lead with an email. How would I make sure the email is valid before I insert it into the database? I am asking because I am inserting a lot of leads at once and don't want problems just because one lead is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Help Article that addresses exactly this question: [How can we check that an email address is in a valid format?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000170904&language=en_US)

> ... you could ensure that an email address is in a format which salesforce.com will consider valid by using a REGEX with syntax like:
>
> ```
> REGEX (
>     UPPER ( EmailField__c ),
>     "^[A-Z0-9._%+-/!#$%&'*=?^_`{|}~]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$"
> )
> ```
>
> Also the below mentioned syntax can be used:
>
> ```
> NOT(REGEX (
>     UPPER ( Field ),
>     "^[A-Z0-9._%+-/!#$%&'*=?^_`{|}~]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$"
> ))
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> NOT(REGEX(
>     Custom_Email_Field__c,
>     '([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})'
> ))
> ```
>
> These two formulas would ensure that all text added on the email field will be consisting of a regular text, followed by the "@" sign, then the domain, followed by the ".com" suffix.

Comment: For completeness this is technically not correct: "followed by the ".com" suffix." it should be "followed by the top level domain (TLD)"

Comment: True. I'll submit that as feedback. Not sure if anyone is listening but it can't hurt.

Comment: Ahhh...I did not follow the links to see it was their documentation